# Calculating total price from input values with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I'm developing a web app where i have to calculate the total price from dynamically added input fields.

Basically i search for items in a database, then there is a dropdown with items matching the search, when i click one of the items, it apears as a row like in the picture below.

[image]

Now what i need is help with getting the total price for all items (Quantity * Price/Unit - Discount(if any)) It has to recalculate this every time i add/remove an item or change one of the variables( Quantity, Price/Unit, Discount).

Here is some code for generating the inputs (I'm using laravel 5.0)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="large 12 columns">
        <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        {!! Form::text("units[]","1") !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>GroupNR</label>
        {!! Form::text("article_group[]",$item->article_group_id) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Item name</label>
        {!! Form::text("article[]",$item->article) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Description</label>
        {!! Form::text("description_en[]",$item->description_en) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Price/Unit</label>
        {!! Form::text("unit_price[]",$item->base_price * $rentalPrice[$days] / 100 + $item->start_price) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Discount</label>
        {!! Form::text("discount[]","0") !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Invoice</label>
        {!! Form::checkbox("invoice[]",null,["checked"]) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>D. Note</label>
        {!! Form::checkbox("delivery_note[]",null,["checked"]) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

For those who are unfamiliar with Laravel, this is the html output:

```
<form id="itemForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input name="units[]" type="text" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>GroupNR</label>
            <input name="article_group[]" type="text" value="2401">
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <label>Item name</label>
            <input name="article[]" type="text" value="Item 1">
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input name="description_en[]" type="text" value="Description">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Price/Unit</label>
            <input name="unit_price[]" type="text" value="7500">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Discount</label>
            <input name="discount[]" type="text" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Invoice</label>
            <input checked="checked" name="invoice[]" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>D. Note</label>
            <input checked="checked" name="delivery_note[]" type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large 12 columns">
            <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input name="units[]" type="text" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>GroupNR</label>
            <input name="article_group[]" type="text" value="1114">
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <label>Item name</label>
            <input name="article[]" type="text" value="Item 2">
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input name="description_en[]" type="text" value="Description">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Price/Unit</label>
            <input name="unit_price[]" type="text" value="345">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Discount</label>
            <input name="discount[]" type="text" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>Invoice</label>
            <input checked="checked" name="invoice[]" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            <label>D. Note</label>
            <input checked="checked" name="delivery_note[]" type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Regards

Comment: it would be the better not to calculate price in jquery/javascript. Send the data with form serialize to the php calculate there and return calculated response

Comment: when you add/remove items, it will submit to php to regenerate the page. To browser its not dynamic. Then why dont just use php to calculate it before your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
  var quantity = parseInt( $(this).find('[name="units[]"]').val(),10)
  var price = parseInt( $(this).find('[name="unit_price[]"]').val(),10)
  total += quantity * price;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d322v98/)**

Comment: I modified this a bit, like so 
http://jsfiddle.net/gpnred22/ (this does not seem to work in the jsfiddle, but works in my application)

However, it only works when i edit a field, not when i add rows to the dom.... Shouldnt that trigger a change event to?

Comment: I ended up fixing it by manually triggering a change event, when pressing the item to add from the dropdown list!

Thanks for all your help

Comment: @JohanBjörklund: glad it helps :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, Can you help me out in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664720/dynamic-input-field-values-are-not-calculating-the-with-the-right-value