# Dynamic input field values are not calculating the with the right value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeignator. My HTML output which is correct for me.

[image]
Now What I am doing is, the user will enter the name of the medication, no of pills and amount so that based on the amount it will calculate the price and display it. Formula is `$single_price=$total_amount/$qty_number;`

[image]

Above image I added `medication name="SIPLA", no of pills=3` and `amount=30`. It will calculate it and display the `single price=10.00`

Everything is working perfectly til now.

Let's talk about the "ADD" button. If any user wants more then one medication then he/she should click on "ADD" button and it will display the same field as above.

I did the same process, I added a `medication name="ZOCON 400", no of pills=4` and `amount=60`. It calculating and displaying the `single price=20.00` which is wrong it should be displayed `single price=15.00`.

1) Why I am getting single price=20.00 because it's talking no of pills=3 which is added in the first medication. So it's talking the first one quantity. It should talk no of pill=4

2) The calculation of the single price is also displaying in both fields. first one as well as second one. I need only in the second one.

3) How to submit this data in the database?

Hope you understand my issue.

[image]

**Code** 
**View**

```
<div class="add_row">
    <input type="text" name="medication_name[]" id="medication_name" class="form_control text_cap" placeholder="medication_name">

    <span class="value_button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control"  name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control"/>
    <span class="value_button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="single_price[]"  id="single_price"  placeholder="single price" />

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total price" />

    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>

  </div>
```

**Ajax and Js**

```
function increaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}

function decreaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment

                $(wrapper).append('<div class="custom_fields"><input type="text" name="medication_name[]" id="medication_name'+ x +'" class="form_control text_cap" placeholder="medication_name"><span class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue('+ x +')" value="Decrease Value">-</span><input type="number" id="number'+ x +'" value="0" name="qty_member[]" /><span class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue('+ x +')" value="Increase Value">+</span><br /><input type="text" class="form_control" name="single_price[]"  id="single_price'+ x +'"  placeholder="single price" />    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price'+ x +'" placeholder="total price" /> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
                $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();

         x--;
    })
$("body").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
  //$('input[id^=single_price]').prop('disabled', true);
    var  total_p_price= $(this).val();
    var qty_number = $('input[id^=number]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/Customer_control/calculate_total_p_price",
        data: {total_p_price: total_p_price,qty_number:qty_number},
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
          //alert(html);
          $('input[id^=single_price]').val(html); 
        }
      });
});

});
```

**Controller**

```
public function calculate_total_p_price(){
  $total_p_price=$this->input->post('total_p_price');
  $qty_number=$this->input->post('qty_number');

  $single_price=$this->Customer_model->calculate_total_p_price($total_p_price,$qty_number);

  echo $single_price;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function calculate_total_p_price($total_p_price,$qty_number){

 // print_r($total_p_price);
if(empty($qty_number) || ($qty_number == 0)){
return 0;
}
elseif(empty($total_p_price) || ($total_p_price == 0)){
return 0;
}
elseif(!empty($total_p_price) && (!empty($qty_number) || ($qty_number>0))){
  $single_price=$total_p_price/$qty_number;
return number_format((float)$single_price, 2, '.', '');
}
else{return 0;}

}
```

Comment: The Add button insert dinamically a new row in your table, am-I right? I think the problem is the calculation use a wrong id.

Comment: Could you dislpay the dynamic html generated after few "add" action? There is maybe an odd incrementation of the "X" value that you use.

Comment: @Eiji, Yes you are right.HTML is already added in the AJAX and js file

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("body").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
  //$('input[id^=single_price]').prop('disabled', true);
    var that = $(this); // CHANGE HERE
    var  total_p_price= that.val();
    var qty_number = that.siblings().find("input[id^=number]").val();
    console.log(qty_number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_row">
    <input type="text" name="medication_name[]" id="medication_name" class="form_control text_cap" placeholder="medication_name">

    <span class="value_button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control"  name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control"/>
    <span class="value_button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="single_price[]"  id="single_price"  placeholder="single price" />

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total price" />

    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>

  </div><div class="add_row">
    <input type="text" name="medication_name[]" id="medication_name" class="form_control text_cap" placeholder="medication_name">

    <span class="value_button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control"  name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control"/>
    <span class="value_button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="single_price[]"  id="single_price"  placeholder="single price" />

    <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" placeholder="total price" />

    <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>

  </div>
```

I can answer first two, for the third question, there is not much info to go on. For 3, are you getting any error? First two questions have similar issue

The issue is in the following syntax `$('input[id^=single_price]').val(html);`

What that does is it selects all the inputs in the dom that match the criteria. In your case you have two inputs that match the criteria and hence both are updated. You need to choose only the one that are in the same row. You can do that using the siblings function that Jquery provides. Change your function in the following way

```
$("body").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
  //$('input[id^=single_price]').prop('disabled', true);
    var that = $(this); // CHANGE HERE
    var  total_p_price= that.val();
    var qty_number = that.siblings('input[id^=number]').val(); // selects only the one closest to it
    $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/Customer_control/calculate_total_p_price",
        data: {total_p_price: total_p_price,qty_number:qty_number},
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
          //alert(html);
          that.siblings('input[id^=single_price]').val(html); 
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but It does not display the calculation value.                    that.siblings('input[id^=single_price]').val(html); It's not displaying the output in the view

Comment: did you also include the line var that = $(this); ?

Comment: Yes I included.

Comment: can you please console log the value of html inside the success callback? I tried at my end and the code works.

Comment: ,console.log(that.siblings('input[id^=single_price]').val(html);) and I am getting like this http://prntscr.com/ke40h0

Comment: Just print the html value that you get from the server in the success callback

Comment: I am getting the value 0. I tried  console.log(html);

Comment: Hmm, is that the value you expect? If not, you need to check the server code that returns the value

Comment: I updated the model code but why it's getting 0 value. before I was getting the right output. 0 is not correct answer when quantity is 3 and total price is 30

Comment: I check everything there is some issue with  var qty_number = that.siblings('input[id^=number]').val(); // selects only the one closest to it
    console.log(qty_number); because I am not getting the quantity value in the console undefined.

Comment: check the snippet above. it correctly prints the value in the console. Make sure to use parseInt to convert string to number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177343/discussion-between-user9437856-and-cdoshi).

Comment: Whatever you suggested, I tried everything but I don't know why still I am getting the undefined in my console. issue is in the     var qty_number = that.siblings('input[id^=number]').val(); It's not catching the qty.

Comment: if I add  var qty_number =  $("input[id^=number]").val(); then I am getting the value. but it's display first qty.

Comment: Hi, its best if you create a jsfiddle or something similar. That way, I can easily debug your issue

Comment: Please check this, https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/pu6qy4zr/19/ this is the simple I added if my div is out of the parent then what method i have to use it?

Comment: Great. Check https://jsfiddle.net/pu6qy4zr/38/ You changed your HTML structure from what was provided in the question. Hence it was not working

Comment: Yes, I change it because I have to use something like this. and add dynamically. give me some time to update it.

Comment: You can update your anser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713135/jquery-siblings-display-undefined-in-alert

Comment: I have updated the answer above. I did not provide answer on that link hence updating it here

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just want to know how many parents class we can use it for the <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" /> this field?

Comment: @cdohi, this is my last experiment. Please help me in this https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/pu6qy4zr/44/

Comment: but it will work only for first quantity single field. what about multiple quantities? I clicked on add button and enter the quantity and total amount and I got the first one quantity value

Comment: you need to basically find the parent of quantity and amount that is for that specific row and use that parent. Use closest jquery function for that purpose

Comment: Oh! that's correct. Now I found the answer.  I added class medication_info in dynamic field as well and I added  var qty_number = $(this).closest("div.medication_info").find("input[id^=number]").val(); and display the correct quantity.

Comment: I update the code in my last jsffidle link. I just want to know is it the right to display the value in the price field  var single_price=that.siblings().find("input[id^=single_price]").val(html); because in the console it's displaying link http://prntscr.com/kghb3l

Answer (score 0):

It also seems you had a bug on the removal/add action.
If you had the case where you add 4 items, so

- 1 (initial)
- 2,3,4 (dynamically generated)

and then decide to remove the 2. 
You decrease `x` by one, witch give you `x=3` and the row `1,3,4`. If now, you add a new item, you get `x+1` and so the collection `1,3,4,4`.

To avoid this pattern, It's maybe a good idea to use the current time (at the `add` execution time) to generate an identifiant to your row.

Since you are working on the HTML contained in a "add_row" div, you can use it as a referent.
Instead of using the "n" value received by your increase/decrease click event, you can get the .parents(".add_row") and then select the .find('.single_price') or .find('.total_p_price') easily

Another approche would be to use a "data-" parameter or a class allowing you to identify easily the current row where you are working.
I probably use something like that :

```
<div class="custom_fields" data-time="1540021654"> <!-- current time on the dynamically added row -->
  <input type="text" name="medication_name[]" data-time="1540021654" class="medication_name">
  <span class="value-button" data-time="1540021654" onclick="decreaseValue" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
  <input type="number" data-time="1540021654" class="qty_member" value="0" name="qty_member[]" />
  <span class="value-button" data-time="1540021654" class="increase_name" onclick="increaseValue">+</span>
  <br />
  <input type="text" class="form_control" data-time="1540021654" name="single_price[]" class="single_price"  />    
  <input type="text" class="form_control" data-time="1540021654" name="total_p_price[]" class="total_p_price" /> 
  <div class="btn_row remove_field"> 
  <span> - </span> Remove  </div>
</div>
```

(I have simplify a little the html for easily find my changes)
With this and jquery, you can find instant all the data you want and update it
$('.single_price data[time="1540021654"]').val() will give you this result and only it.

Another mistake is, you are generating buttons with an id static, like `<span class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue('+ x +')" value="Increase Value">`
This is a mistakes because id should be Unique.

Comment: Oh! I haven't notice that you right. If I add 1 (initial) and dynamic(2,3,4,5) and if I remove 3 then added one more dynamic field and this time dynamic fields are(2,4,5,5). which is totally wrong. Give me time to implement your code

Comment: Last issue I rectify it. Id is unique now. I just want to know how you are adding the   data-time="1540021654" dynamically?

Comment: any more help in this?Please

Comment: To add data- dynamically, use the Jquery syntax. `$('input.single_price').data('time',154001234)` should work

Comment: Where should i add above script? I mean, In which function?