# Jquery siblings display undefined in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery siblings display undefined
I have quantity field and the total amount field when user enter anything in the total amount field then I have to display the quantity on alert. I don't care about the quantity for a time because I have to understand that why my jquery siblings is not working. When I enter any number then I am getting undefined in the alert.

This is not my whole project, This is the part of the project which I have to understand the siblings. I upload the code to the below link.

for example I have quantity and total price. If i use   var qty_number=$("#number1").val();
 then it will work for the only single field. Now I have added more button If any user clicked on add more then it will display quantity + total price + remove button. The user can add up to 10 fields. Now when the user enters anything in the total price I have to display the quantity of that row.

if my div is out of the parent then what method i have to use it?

Would you help me out in this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/pu6qy4zr/19/

```js
function increaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}

function decreaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}
$(".custom").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {

  var that = $(this); // CHANGE HERE
  var total_p_price = that.val();
  var qty_number = that.siblings("input[id^=number]").val();
  alert(qty_number);
  console.log(qty_number);
});
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="plus_minus">
    <span class="value_button decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control" />
    <span class="value_button increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quantity input is not in the same div with the total input (they dont have the same parent (container) so it's like they are not siblings,  If you put the two input in the same div the quantity will be displayed in the alert. 
here the code:

```
<div class="custom">
    <div class="plus_minus">
        <span class="value_button decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
        <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control"  name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control"/>
        <span class="value_button increase"  onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>

<input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Here a link to understand jquery siblings : https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @cblnfo009, Thanks for the reply. That's good information but in case my total input is out of the div then which method I have to use in Jquery?

Comment: There are many ways to get the input quantity value, since you are using jquery here and your input has an id the easiest way is to look for the value using the id like this:  var qty_number=$("#number1").val();

Comment: @cblnfo009, Yes, that's correct, I can use var qty_number=$("#number1").val(); and get the value in the alert. Why I am using it because I have to add quantity input and total amount field dynamically. so that   var qty_number=that.siblings("input[id^=number]").val(); will catch the nearst qyantity value.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm my comment: 
to get the display the quantity value using the id:

```js
function increaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}

function decreaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}
$(".custom").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {

  var that = $(this); // CHANGE HERE
  var total_p_price = that.val();
  var qty_number=$("#number1").val();
  alert(qty_number);
  console.log(qty_number);
});
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="plus_minus">
    <span class="value_button decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control" />
    <span class="value_button increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_p_price[]" id="total_p_price" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will not work with dynamic field. It will catch only the first quantity. that's the reason I mention in the question that this is not a whole project this is the part of the project.

Comment: are you creating the fields dynamically?

Comment: if so you may need to use jquery : .children() . I am not sure what are you doing exactly.

Comment: @cblnfo009, I am so sorry if you haven't understood my question. might be I haven't explained it better.  let's explain in details: I have quantity and total price. You answer will work for the only single field. Now I have added more button If any user clicked on add more then it will display quantity + total price + remove button. The user can add up to 10 fields. Now when the user enters anything in the total price I have to display the quantity of that row.

Comment: do you have a sample code for that? so i could help you

Comment: @cblnfo009, Please check this question. 3 days before I ask a question. You will understand my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664720/dynamic-input-field-values-are-not-calculating-the-with-the-right-value