# Can we use nested table after the `<tr></tr>`?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I am displaying the record from database in the table list. Also, I have a follow-up button in each row, If any user clicks on followup button then a popup will open for a specific user with details.

Or any other idea to handle this issue?

I tried to use something like this

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr>

<div style="display:none">
<table>
<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</tbody>
</table>
```

**Full code**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Products</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Order Id</th>
                        <th>Mobile </th>
                        <th>Shipping address</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php  $n=1;
                         foreach ($cust_personal as $row)  
                         { $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->o_id));//encrpt the id 
                            ?>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $n;?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row->c_firstname;?>&nbsp; <?php echo $row->c_lastname;?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row->o_product_brandname;?></td>    
                              <td><?php echo $row->o_product_qty;?></td>  
                              <td><?php echo $row->o_order_no;?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row->c_mobileno;?></td>  
                              <td><?php echo $row->c_s_address;?></td>
        <td> <a  href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_icon pending" onclick="approve(this)" data-id="<?=$row->o_id;?>"> <span>Pending</span></a>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('Customer_control/get_customer_view?key='.$encryption_id)?>" class="table_icon view">View</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_icon archive" onclick="followup(this)" data-id="<?=$row->o_id;?>">Followup</a>
                        </tr>

     <div id="popup-<?=$row->o_id;?>" style="display: none;" class="class="view_popup_profile">
      <div class="profile_content">
    <div class="profile_header clearfix">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead><th>sub</th></thead>
                    <tbody><tr><td>maths</td></tr></tbody>
                </table>
</div></div>
                </div>
                       <?php } $n++; ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function followup(obj) 
            {
                var id = $(obj).data('id');
                //console.log(id);
                $("#popup-"+id).show();  
            }
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

This is the output I am getting it.
[image]

Why I need a nested table because when I am adding the below code and click on followup button then I am getting the popup on full screen.

```
</tr>
 <div id="popup-<?=$row->o_id;?>" style="display: none;">
    <!--more details here-->
      </div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I added a table in the popup to display the following list then it's not working.

```
    </tr>
     <div id="popup-<?=$row->o_id;?>" style="display: none;">
            <table border="1">
                    <thead><th>sub</th></thead>
                    <tbody><tr><td>maths</td></tr></tbody>
                </table>
</div>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**css**

```
        .view_popup_profile {
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 9; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
/* Modal Content */
.profile_content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    max-width: 922px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
/* The Close Button */

.profile_header {
    padding: 1px 20px;
    background-color: #fafafc;
    color: white;
    /* min-height: 58px; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.profile_header:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-top: 16px solid #f7f7f7;
    position: absolute;
}
.profile_body {
    padding: 35px 50px;
}
.profile_footer {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fdfdfe;
    color: #858585;
}
p{color: #000;}
    /* Add Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
 from {
 top: -500px;
 opacity: 0
}
 to {
 top:25%;
 opacity: 1
}
}
 @keyframes slideIn {
 from {
 top: -500px;
 opacity: 0
}
 to {
 top:25%;
 opacity: 1
}
}
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
 from {
 opacity: 0
}
 to {
 opacity: 1
}
}
 @keyframes fadeIn {
 from {
 opacity: 0
}
 to {
 opacity: 1
}
}
```

Comment: Yes you can nest a table, but it needs to be inside one of the table cells, between `<td>` and `</td>` or between `<th>` and `</th>`. That's the way tables work: all content needs to be in a header or data cell.

Comment: @lurker, I tried to use <td>my popup code</td> but it's creating the extra space in the table.

Comment: can you tell us what the output is (with a screencap) and what you'd like it to look like? You didn't include specifics/details.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, ok I will explain in the details. just give me the moment I am updating my question.

Comment: OK. Matter 'o fact, have a read through this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced - There are examples of nested tables. Am actually in that area myself *lol!* Just doing myself a refresher course, as it were. Yeah, even I have to read those over again myself sometimes :-)

Comment: I recommend [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/validity/bbicmjjbohdfglopkidebfccilipgeif) for validating the current document. The ONLY permitted children of `<tbody>` is one or more `<td>` elements. So no `<div>` and no `<table>` as you have it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: *Evenin'* @Mike Seems like we're on the same site. heh :-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Looks that way, don't it!

Comment: @Mike Yep! I was actually already in that area when I saw the question. As I was telling the OP, that I too need to go a refresher course every once in a while, just to keep me sharp ;-) I've been doing way too much back-end work for quite some time now.

Comment: @user9437856 *Hm...*, I'm wondering if using ajax for this would be better with a popup modal; seems to fit the bill as to what I think you want to do here. That way you could have user's info popup inside an already formatted table based on their data alone using dynamically assignment variables.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I updated my code and explanation, I know it's totally different from last code.

Comment: about your *"then I am getting the popup on full screen."* - If the popup works and all that it's doing is being full screen, then isn't this a CSS issue more than anything? If so, then just modify your (CSS) rule(s) to fit instead a set constraint width/height or by percentage, unless I'm not grasping.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I added the css as well, I added lorem content instated of the table. I have to display the table inside the popup. If  I add my popup code outside of the <tr></tr> then I am getting only last user id details.

Comment: Try to run a `while` loop rather than a `foreach`; seeing what you said just now ^ and your `width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */` seems to be the culprit as far as full window goes. Reduce it to 50% and try it again.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Now it's too complicated. right? ok. I will try it.

Comment: Heh, just a tad :-) Try putting your first `<table>` tag and some `<tr>` and `<td>` and then place your looped data fetching inside that with another set of `<table>` tags just before it. That'll be it for me soon; it's getting late and 5am comes awfully fast. See what you can do with what was said. Look at your HTML source when you're trying/testing and you'll probably see something.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Thanks for the help, I will try it. If you get a time then please check my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713135/jquery-siblings-display-undefined-in-alert

Comment: you're welcome. I'll see what I can do; *nite!*

Comment: @Marvin, Nope My scenario is totally different as compare to your answer.

Comment: First of all, I said an answer, not my answer. Also, if you have a different problem you want to solve I would consider modifying the title to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can make nested tables. Make everything like a regular table until the `td` tag. Inside this, make the table tag and everything. What you were doing was first of all, bad indentation (which I tidied in the JSFiddle

This is what a cell of a table would look like:

```
<td>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>sub</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>maths</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

You can also use colspan and rowspan, which has a similar result, to prevent getting carried away by a complex design.

```
<tr>
 <td rowspan = 2>10</td>
 <td> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>sub</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>math>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they want to have something dynamic here. This is just an "HTML 101" example really. And nothing that already hasn't been said (in comments). I won't downvote this, but I certainly won't be upvoting neither; *just being honest*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was writing this answer while the other one was posted. Also, he asked how to make nested tables, and I answered the question.

Comment: Oh, I've no argument about that Marvin. I just have a feeling that they're looking for a dynamic solution, rather than a static one.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was also going to add that they could use col and row span instead of nesting tables as a suggestion but I had to post the first part of my answer first.

Comment: If you mean user interaction, data, client-side, and php, then you are right. I have had no experience with PHP, so I just wanted to give him an outline of what he should be going with.

Comment: Let's see what the OP has to say. I think they're probably busy editing their post as they said in comments. *But*, that was almost 15 mins. and Mike and I have given them a few references to look into, maybe that's what they doing, I don't know. The OP hasn't gotten back (to me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177532/discussion-between-marvin-and-funk-forty-niner).

Comment: Well, I take back what I said earlier; I find that it was explained and basically answered what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely can add tables within tables but keep in mind add them in the table cell which is `<td></td>` 
Below is the reference link and don't be afraid to try it out!

ref : https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/nestingtables.html

(p.s.. if you worry about creating extra spaces in cells you can modify the cell's or the nested table's style in css such as adjusting margin or padding.

**Addon:**
You could try taking the `data` from the clicked link using jquery and remove the `onclick=followup(this)` from the link

Add this in your script and try it out:

```
$(".archive").on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $("#popup-"+id).show();
})
```

Comment: Yes, I read the post before uploading the question. I tried <td style="display: none;" id="popup-<?=$row->o_id;?>"> 
     <div >
    <table border="1">
     <thead><th>sub</th></thead>
     <tbody><tr><td>maths</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
   </td>

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the table cell? popup modal or nested table?

Comment: I added the style display:none for space but this is not a cell, This is the popup which I have to cover on the full screen. I added in the question that I need a popup. Or is there any other way to handle this issue?

Comment: Why are you putting them in the table then? Just put them at the end of the HTML.

Comment: @Mike, If I am adding at the end of the HTML then when I am clicking on the followup button then it's talking only the last id value

Comment: @user9437856 Then you have a mistake somewhere. To diagnose it we would need to see your code.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks, Let me check.give me some time to check

Comment: @user9437856 so i presume that you are saying that you expect that the user will able to view the relevant data based on which button in the row the user clicks?

Comment: @gitguddoge, Yes, If I add my popup code out of table then it's displaying only the last user id.

Comment: @user9437856 i added some code sample and hope you try it in my way and see if it could help :)

Comment: @gitguddoge, but issue is, It's displaying only the last record in the popup

Comment: @user9437856 did you inspect the element of each of the link to make sure that the `data-id` has different id for each link?

Comment: @user9437856 you can somehow use **jquery** to trigger button clicking in the _console panel_ to figure out why is only the last `id` being get called or the `data-id` may have same id in the end

Comment: @gitguddoge, Yes, data-id is different in each of the link

Comment: @user9437856 could you `console.log($(this).data('id'))` of the link when you click on it and check for each different link clicked?

Comment: @gitguddoge, In console I am getting the correct id. I mean I click on 1, displayed 1, clicked on 2 displayed 2. but popup not displaying.

Comment: @user9437856 so in this case the link's `data-id` is correct and now the problem is the popup table... could you explicity use jquery to trigger the popup in _console tab_ such as `$('#popup-1').show()` and at least try 2 different popup tables?

Comment: I deleted id 1 before, I have 2 and 3 id and so on. This id for testing. I added$('#popup-2').show() in console and display the popup, $('#popup-3').show() then it's not display the popup

Comment: @user9437856 and this seems that the problem is popup table itself now. Any warning or error shown when the popup-3 is not shown? Did you try to `hide()` the popup-2 before `show()` popup-3?

Comment: @gitguddoge, give me the time I will check again my whole code.